# Snaps does not work anymore on my Ubuntu Studio 20.10 (Plasma Desktop)

Tags: kde, snap, 20.10

Everytime I try to run a snap app, it does not run.
When I try to run the app on terminal, it shows me the following message:

```
cannot snap-exec: cannot exec "/snap/skype/164/snap/command-chain/snapcraft-runner": input/output error
```

System Details:

- Operating System: Ubuntu Studio 20.10
- KDE Plasma Version: 5.19.5
- KDE Frameworks Version: 5.74.0
- Qt Version: 5.14.2
- Kernel Version: 5.8.0-44-lowlatency
- OS Type: 64-bit
- Processors: 4 × Intel® Core™ i7-2620M CPU @ 2.70GHz
- Memory: 9.6 GiB of RAM
- Graphics Processor: Mesa DRI Intel® HD Graphics 3000